# Date picker displays in 2 different dates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, formatting, momentjs

I recently implemented a date picker with moment.js. For some reason its displaying the wrong date. I displayed the date outside the date picker and it was fine. I console.logged the variables to see what was being stored and that turned out to be the format I wanted. However when I call the data in the date picker it displays in the wrong format. It should be exactly the same whats being outputted underneath the date picker. Can someone explain where I'm going wrong?

**Date picker and correct date being outputted underneath:**

[image]

```
<div class="datepicker-container">
        <div class="date-from">
          From:
          <datepicker date-set="{{yesterday}}" selector="form-control" date-max-limit="{{today}}" class="date-picker">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Choose a date"/>
              <span class="input-group-addon" style="cursor: pointer">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
          </datepicker>
        </div>
        <div class="date-too">
          To:
          <datepicker date-set="{{today}}" selector="form-control" date-min-limit="{{yesterday}}" class="date-picker">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Choose a date"/>
              <span class="input-group-addon" style="cursor: pointer">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
              </span>
            </div>
          </datepicker>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h4>{{yesterday}} and {{today}}</h4>
```

**Defining the date:**

[image]

```
var currentDate = moment(new Date()).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
console.log("1", currentDate);

$scope.today = currentDate.toString();
console.log("2", $scope.today);

var yesterdaysDate = moment(new Date()).subtract(1, 'days').format("DD/MM/YYYY");
console.log("3", yesterdaysDate);

$scope.yesterday = yesterdaysDate.toString();
console.log("4", $scope.yesterday);
```

Comment: Could you provide the `datepicker` directive/component declaration?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, I formatted the date with the date picker instead of moment.

**Date picker:**

```
<div class="datepicker-container">
    <div class="date-from">
      From:
      <datepicker date-set="{{yesterday}}" date-format="dd/MM/yyyy" selector="form-control" date-max-limit="{{today}}" class="date-picker">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Choose a date"/>
          <span class="input-group-addon" style="cursor: pointer">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
      </datepicker>
    </div>
    <div class="date-too">
      To:
      <datepicker date-set="{{today}}" date-format="dd/MM/yyyy" selector="form-control" date-min-limit="{{yesterday}}" class="date-picker">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Choose a date"/>
          <span class="input-group-addon" style="cursor: pointer">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
      </datepicker>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h4>{{yesterday}} and {{today}}</h4>
```

**Moment:**

```
var currentDate = moment(new Date());
console.log("1", currentDate);

$scope.today = currentDate.toString();
console.log("2", $scope.today);

var yesterdaysDate = moment(new Date()).subtract(1, 'days');
console.log("3", yesterdaysDate);

$scope.yesterday = yesterdaysDate.toString();
console.log("4", $scope.yesterday);
```